# Erro ao inserir data na sprint no jira

Tags: datetime, time, scrum, jira

Quando tento iniciar minha sprint aparece esse erro no jira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve alterar a a primeira letra do mês para minúscula então a data vai ficar 19/dez/17 06:33 PM.